# Are some Chamber options just impossible to get without Split paths?

Tags: hades

Are some Chamber options just impossible to get without Split paths?

Following this [RNG Manipulation Guide](https://www.speedrun.com/hades/guide/jxpkj), trying to see how good I can get my first run...

Beyond the first Athena, I'm trying to get as many Keys as I can, so my second room was a Key, then I want my third to be a Boon room, and it seems it can be Athena, Dionysus or Artemis, the latter two after ~15 Casts... haven't seen Ares, the last possibility yet.

Note for all testers, Discord confirms that Casts that immediately pick up are A-OK for manipulation!

But from there, I can't immediately get another Key? It seems like it's always Darkness in my fourth Chamber, at least on all the Athenas I've had and the four Artemises...

I had to reroll my initial seed such that Room 3 was a Split path to get a Key... I wonder if that's truly necessary... Well, it seems I *might* be stuck at Room 7 always being Darkness, if Room 6 avoids Darkness by being the Inferno-Bomber minibosses. Did ~15 tries?